# Why use gradient descent on Deep Nets / RNNs when cost function is not convex?

Tags: neural-network, rnn, gradient-descent, optimization, genetic-algorithms

Why do we use gradient descent on very non-convex loss functions such as in Deep nets / RNNs rather than a heuristic search (genetic algorithms, simulated annealing, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your cost function is not convex, any minimization algorithm will do its job - including gradient descent. That said, a standard gradient descent is a *local* optimization procedure and can only ever guarantee a local minimum, not a global one. For quite a few applications, a good local minimum is good enough - for others, a lot of effort is put into using “global” optimization algorithms (such as genetic/evolutionary, simulated annealing, scatter search, multi start techniques, direct/multilevel searches etc...). Those algorithms are definitely more powerful but they are also significantly slower in converging to a good, potentially global, minimum. And none of them can guarantee global optimality unless you allow them a veeeeeeery large number of functions evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

Because in practice gradient decent approaches work better than any other available alternative, despite the lack of convergence guarantees to global optima.

And, in any case, metaheuristics do not offer any practical convergence guarantees for this kind of functions either.